# How lstm processes a different number of features from the previous layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

For example we have LSTM layer with output=2 and two variants of input shape:

1. `(n_samples=1, n_timestep=1, n_features=4)`
2. `(n_samples=1, n_timestep=1, n_features=2)`

How LSTM processes this different number features as input and constant feature as output?

code example:

```python
inputs1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.constant([[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]]]), dtype=tf.float32)
##tf.Tensor([[[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]]], shape=(1, 1, 4), dtype=float32)


inputs2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.constant([[[0.1,0.2]]]), dtype=tf.float32)
##tf.Tensor([[[0.1 0.2]]], shape=(1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)

output1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(inputs1)
##tf.Tensor([[[-0.08766557 -0.01480309]]], shape=(1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)

output2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, return_sequences=True)(inputs2)
##tf.Tensor([[[-0.02775455  0.02273378]]], shape=(1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

They only difference your data has, is the amount of timesteps, which are represented by the last dimension (4 or 2). The LSTM itself unwraps the timesteps, and recurrently calculates your output value, while it iterates through each timestep. Thats why an LSTM takes different lenghts of inputs

Comment: But the number of timesteps is not the last dimension, because the last dimension is the number of feature per timestep